# How to combine various discrete probabilities?

Tags: probability

See following link for a live example of sentiment analysis
http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sentiment/rntnDemo.html

If I have a document having following three sentences

1. This movie doesn't care about cleverness, wit or any other kind of
   intelligent humor.
2. Those who find ugly meanings in beautiful
   things are corrupt without being charming.
3. There are slow and
   repetitive parts, but it has just enough spice to keep it
   interesting.

*
After analysis I get the result as shown below for each sentence, which shows the probability of that sentence being

```
Very Negative, Negative , Neutral, Positive, Very Positive. 
[0.0906, 0.8188, 0.0708, 0.0161, 0.0038]
```

For example:

```
text: Sentence 1
scoreDistr: [0.0906, 0.8188, 0.0708, 0.0161, 0.0038]

text: Sentence 2
scoreDistr: [0.025, 0.0337, 0.038, 0.0271, 0.8762]

text: Sentence 3
scoreDistr: [0.2019, 0.6905, 0.084, 0.0129, 0.0106]
```

How can I combine these three **sentence probability** and come up with a score which can be applied at the document level ? So basically how can I combine these probability to know the overall sentiment of three sentences together whether the overall document is Very Negative, Negative, Neutral , Positive or Very Positive.

```
scoreDistr: [0.0906, 0.8188, 0.0708, 0.0161, 0.0038]
scoreDistr: [0.025, 0.0337, 0.038, 0.0271, 0.8762]
scoreDistr: [0.2019, 0.6905, 0.084, 0.0129, 0.0106]
```

Comment: could you edit the question, further clarifying what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Edited with details of the problem statement and example. Hope now the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you combine all the probabilities together and plot them ? Since your document is just a collection of sentences.

If you'd really like to combine the distributions you could look into using Kullback-Leibler Divergence to choose an approximation for your overall distribution.

Here is some explanation to that - 
https://www.countbayesie.com/blog/2017/5/9/kullback-leibler-divergence-explained